# Synchronize online SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization, replication

As I found this can be done with merge replication in SQL Server. But I have only one main server and many small ones(with Express edition installed on them).

Let me explain:

There is the main (*big*) office with SQL Server Standard edition installed on its server. And there are many offices across the country with with their own small servers, because they have no constant connect to the main *big* server. Tho there are several computers in local offices to work with their local server. So I've decided to install Express on locals and Standard on *big* and somehow set synchronization solution between all of them, so that the database can be changed on *big* and locals seperately and the changes and conflicts can be handled by some rule.

Can you suggest me the right solution if im wrong? or correct me.. I think I can't do all of this with Express editions installed on locals :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express can only function as a Subscriber (in Replication)... you won't be able to publish your local changes back to big. It's only from big to locals.

Comment: Thank you Nestor.. Ive read the same. So i'll have to implement my own model of synchronization.

Comment: Found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/sync/archive/2010/01/05/new-code-sample-database-sync-sql-server-and-sql-server-express.aspx recently

Comment: Yes.. that was recently added. Thanks for your comment!